# How to get KML or JSON data of (polygon) area using Google Map URL using JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like get the KML or JSON data for the red polygon (as far as I know it's called polygon) area. I want to display the area in a custom map of my application and I will place some markers within this area.

You can check this example: https://goo.gl/maps/7SIeg

[image]

I just need to grab the KML or JSON object of the co-ordinates the red marked area.

Comment: You can't retrieve this information from the Google Maps API. You should either hand-draw it (using geojson.io) as an estimated area, or find open data for that region and convert it to GeoJSON or KML.

Comment: @kolor is right. You can not export Google Maps data as a KML or JSON. But if you want to show the places like in the public maps, you can use Places API by Google: https://developers.google.com/places/. And request places from that region in your map.

Comment: Alternatively there are other ways to get the Google Maps data which could be accessed with the use of one or more APIs. Check out which API(s) provide the type of data you are looking for and use them in your app/website. https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 3):

I had same question.But, no there is no option that you can get KML of searched area and google maps will extract you a polygon.

But you can use various resources like

http://www.mapmash.in/kmlpolygon.html

http://geojson.io/

to create polygons yourself.

Regards, 
Suyash